Does the Samsung Galaxy smart ring have a flight mode?
Is there a flight mode in the Samsung Galaxy smart ring?

what do you mean by flight mode?

@jsotola the common mode on most wireless electronic devices which disabled wireless communication for use in flight (also known as airplane mode), I suppose.

@jcaron, yes, that's what I mean

It's doesn't. Ringconn and oura do.
Anyone who says it has no need for airplane mode has no clue about smart rings and is giving rubbish advice
Google is free people. Read up before commenting on a info request.

You can improve your answer by providing a reference. Just you saying it, without a reason or reference does not make it right.

Unless I have missed something, it does not have a SIM, physical or electronic.  So, it does not need flight mode.  Bluetooth and wifi are allowed to be used on the plane.
So, it has no need for a Flight Mode

I would love to have a mode where all wireless communication is disabled,  and I can sync only once in a while, because I'm wary of having something continuously sending wireless signals being so close to my body. When I wear my samsung galaxy watch with flight mode turned off for some time, I sense a strange feeling on my hand around the watch. When I turn the flight mode off, that feeling goes away after some time.  Hence, I use my smartwatch with flight mode on for most of the time, and I sync it occasionally.  Before deciding to buy a smart ring, wanted to ensure it does have a flight mode
